# EclipseLink JPA enhancer

Tags: eclipselink

Can anybody specify/point to good instructions how to activate JPA enhancer (weaving) with EcliopsLink. I understand that speeds the DB access .
By default I see that eclipselink.weaving=false in Eclipse project login.properties file.

I have found this link http://java.dzone.com/articles/jpa-performance-optimization
to be not so clear i.e I need know how to activate run_time or build time weaving.

and where is the "application's EntityManagerFactory Spring bean" set (if needed) ?

Should I use Lazy fetch in my annotaions when weaving is active ?

Answer (score 0):

How to configure dynamic (runtime) weaving with javaagent is explained in [Configuring dynamic weaving](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Dynamic_Weaving). Detailed description about how to configure static (build time) weaving is explained in details in [Configuring Static Weaving](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Static_Weaving)

"application's EntityManagerFactory Spring bean"  is often set in applicationContext.xml, but that stuff is specific for Spring, and maybe you do not plan to use it.

Weaving does not force you to use lazy fetching.